# What is a regular expression for control characters?

Tags: java, regex, ascii, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to match a control character in the form \^c where c is any valid character for control characters. I have this regular expression, but it's not currently working: `\\[^][@-z]`

I think the problem lies with the fact that the caret character (^) is part of the regular expressions parsing engine.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense to me.  Is there a backslash there? Are these real control characters, or some ASCII sequence implying the same?  Why go \c@ .. \cZ only?  There are others, you know.

Comment: Why are you putting the caret in a character class anyway?

Comment: I'm trying to match the literal text for the control characters, not the control characters themselves.

Comment: Control-X is defined as the character whose code point is the  result of `^-ing` the code point of `X` with the code point of `@`; that is, bit 0x40.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Match an ASCII text string of the form `^X` using the pattern `\^.`, nothing more.  Match an ASCII text string of the form `\^X` with the pattern `\\\^.`.  You may wish to constrain that dot to `[?@_\[\]^\\]`, so `\\\^[A-Z?@_\[\]^\\]`.  It’s easier to read as `[?\x40-\x5F]` for the bracketed character class, hence `\\\^[?\x40-\x5F]` for a literal BACKSLASH, followed by a literal CIRCUMFLEX, followed by something that turns into one of the valid control characters.

Note that that is the result of printing out the pattern, or what you’d read from a file. It’s what you need to pass to the regex compiler.  If you have it as a string literal, you must of course double each of those backslashes. `` `\\\\\\^[?\\x40-\\x5F]" `` Yes, it is insane looking, but that is because Java does not support regexes directly as Groovy and Scala — or Perl and Ruby — do.  Regex work is always easier without the extra bbaacckksslllllaasshheesssssess. :)

If you had real control characters instead of indirect representations of them, you would use `\pC` for all literal code points with the property GC=Other, or `\p{Cc}` for just GC=Control.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand \pC. I'm writing a lexical analyzer using JLex and I need to recognize valid control character sequences in a string and translate them to their ASCII equivalents. For example, the string "\^g" would print the bell character or cause the computer speaker to beep. I need a regular expression to match control character sequences like "\^g".

Comment: @pcman: Do you have a literal BACKSLASH followed by a literal CIRCUMFLEX followed by a character that is one of `[A-Z@?\[\]_^]`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to match the literal text as it would appear in a string.

Comment: This matches accents as well

Answer (score 4):

Check this out: https://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html . You should be able to use \cA to \cZ to find the control characters..

Comment: What about `\c?` for DELETE (U+7F)?  Did you know that Java thinks `\c{` is `;` and that `\c;` is `{`?  They forgot to check that result is `\p{Cc}`.  Oops!

Comment: Stale link. The page still exists, but the info about `\c` has moved to https://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html