# Java regular expression \cx (control characters)

Tags: java, regex, perl, control-characters

Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern` says `\cx` represents *The control character corresponding to x*. So I thought `Pattern.compile()` would reject a `\c` followed by any character other than `[@-_]`, but it doesn't!

As @tchrist commented on one of the answers to [What is a regular expression for control characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893759/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-control-characters), range is not checked at all. I tested a couple characters from higher blocks and also astral planes, looks like it merely flips the 7th lowest bit of the codepoint value.

So is it a Javadoc bug or an implementation bug or am I misunderstanding something? Is `\cx` a Java-invented syntax or is it supported by other regex engines, especially Perl? How is it handled there?

Comment: You forgot `\c?`. `^?` refers to the `DEL` control character (`0x7F`).

Comment: @ikegami Yes you are right. I keep forgetting 0x7F as it always stays in the corner alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All versions of Perl behave the same for the following escapes:

- When `\c` is followed by an ASCII uppercase letter or one of `@[\]^_?`,

  `chr(ord($char) ^ 0x40)`

  This provides full coverage of all ASCII control characters (`0x00`..`0x1F`, `0x7F`).

  ```
  \c@ === \x00
  \cA === \x01
  ...
  \cZ === \x1A
  \c[ === \x1B
  \c\ === \x1C   # Sometimes \c\\ is needed.
  \c] === \x1D
  \c^ === \x1E
  \c_ === \x1F
  \c? === \x7F
  ```
- When `\c` is followed by an ASCII lowercase letter,

  `chr(ord($char) ^ 0x60)`

  This makes the escape case-insensitive.

  ```
  \ca === \cA === \x01
  ...
  \cz === \cZ === \x1A
  ```

---

No other sequence make sense, but error checking was only introduced in Perl 5.20.

- ≥5.20,

  - When `\c` is followed by a space, an ASCII digit or one of `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>{|}~`,

    `chr(ord($char) ^ 0x40)`, but warns (`is more clearly written simply as`).
  - When `\c` is followed by an ASCII control character (`0x00`..`0x1F`, `0x7F`) or a non-ASCII character (≥`0x80`),

    Fatal error `Character following "\c" must be printable ASCII`.
- <5.20,

  - When `\c` is followed by a space, an ASCII digit, one of one of `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>{|}~` or an ASCII control character (`0x00`..`0x1F`, `0x7F`),

    `chr(ord($char) ^ 0x40)`
  - When `\c` is followed by character ≥`0x100`,

    Total garbage (`chr(ord(substr(encode_utf8($char, 0, 1)) ^ 0x40) . encode_utf8($char, 1)`).
  - When `\c` is followed by character `0x80`..`0xFF`,

    Depending on the internal storage format of the string, produces either `chr(ord($char) ^ 0x40)` or the same total garbage as for characters ≥`0x100`.